# How to add zeros if less than 4 decimal and remove if more?

Tags: javascript

Can someone show me how to write a function that adds 0's after the decimal if less than four digits appear after the decimal until 4 decimal spots long and trim digits from far right of decimal in excess of 4. These are strings. Don't want any rounding. For display only, not calculations. So for example:

719.843797 should remove last two digits to be 719.8437
21.947 should add one 0 to be 21.9470
1.3456 no change

Comment: I think it really means finding the decimal point, then determining the proper length to truncate or pad the string. First pad with 4 0's then perform a truncation to the final wanted length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `toFixed` or any sort of multiplication may result in rounding problems. Treating number as a string allows to avoid them. The function below passes all your given usecases. But this is kinda hacky. Though I'm not sure if there is a better way to fit your requirements.

```js
function truncate4(x) {
   var parts = x.toString().split('.'); // this is not i18n proof :(
   var integral = parts[0];
   var decimal = parts[1] || ''; // might be integer
   return integral + '.' + (decimal + '0000').substr(0, 4) 
}

console.log(truncate4(719.843797));
console.log(truncate4(21.947));
console.log(truncate4(1.3456));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should match

```
function arrondir(num){
  var str = num.toString();
  var index = str.indexOf(".");
  var decimal = str.substr(index+1);
  var integer = str.substr(0, index);
  if (decimal.length < 4)
    for (var i = 0; i < 5 - decimal.length; i++)
      decimal = decimal.concat("0");
  else decimal = decimal.substr(0,4);
  return integer.concat(".").concat(decimal);
}

console.log(arrondir(719.84));          // 719.8400
console.log(arrondir(719.84657963657)); // 719.8465
```